# /tools/post-feedback times out

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

I can't access [anonymous and low rep post feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback) page because every time I try I get time out.

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that one, too, and wanted to write a bug report on that as well, but the page says _“Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified”_, and I’d like to hope that that’s true.

Comment: According to [an employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349663/500-error-on-tools-post-feedback#comment1170258_349663), it's probably because it's taking too long to load the data and then the server kills it due to it timing out.